# Setting python for RStudio under Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, rstudio

Can't change python being used when install_keras run from RStudio within Anaconda

I have several versions of Python installed on my Windows 10 box: Python 2.7, Python 3.6, plus the pythons that appear to have been installed with Anaconda. I have RStudio installed via Anaconda.

I am trying to use the keras library in my R code. I run 'install_keras()' and receive the following error:

```
Error: Error 1 occurred while checking for python architecture
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\Python27\/python.exe" -c "import sys; import platform; 
sys.stdout.write(platform.architecture()[0])"' had status 1
```

I have tried running install_keras using the method and conda settings:

```
install_keras(method="conda", conda="C:/Development/Anaconda35/Scripts")
```

But I still get the same error. I have also tried resetting the PATH and RETICULATE_PYTHON environmental variables, using Sys.setenv and use_python() and it doesn't seem to help.

Sys.which('PYTHON') does show the correct executable that I want to use.

Yes, my environment variables did have that Python set first in the path. But changing that didn't seem to help.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling keras, both the R library and the 'conda' (pip) python library. That didn't help.

I'm assuming at this point that there's some configuration or setting file with this set, but I can't seem to find it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to set "PythonPath" to your preferred python.exe and see if that works? Global/win paths and others can overlap and the first one is always used when found. With some libraries I have noticed a specific pythonpath often fixes those random errors.

Comment: PYTHONPATH points to the libraries (Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages and Anaconda3\Lib), which are correct.

Comment: As your error/warning message says "running command '"C:\Python27\/python.exe" -c "imp …" do you have any idea why it is showing "C:\Python27\/python.exe" instead of proper windows path? Typo somewhere, a mixed / path with \ path or unneeded escape character?

Comment: I assume it's getting 'C:\Python27\' from some config value. But i can't find where it might be. As I mentioned above, I'm guessing it's somewhere that Anaconda has it set, since I've uninstalled and reinstalled keras with the PATH changed. But I don't know where.

Comment: It seems to be quite a complex how this frames try to find a proper version of python to use. Apparently the one having first import and/or satisfying the install requirements (=proper libraries installed) will be used, but they can be overrun with things like use_python, use_virtualenv and use_condaenv. I would suggest a mass search for the path, trying use_condaenv (make sure your conda has proper version installed first) or if SOME python version works in your r project, maybe rename python27 temporarily and symlink working python into it, to see what happens?

Comment: Aside Setting  Environment path !Could you please try Same in Python 3.6-3.9 , as supported python versions are python 3.6-3.9 now.                                                
Reference-https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows